# Can't change the space before and after sections

Tags: spacing, sectioning

I'm here again with another question.

Today I was trying to change the spaces before (double spacing) and after (single spacing) my sections, subsections and sub subsections. I've tried `\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{1.5em}{0.5em}` but it hadn't changed the spaces.

I've already checked other answers, but can't figure it out what is wrong.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,hidelinks]{article} % Fonte 12, Papel A4, Artigo

% Pacotes %

\usepackage[scaled]{helvet} % Fonte Helvetica
\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\sfdefault} % Designa Helvetica como fonte padrão
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel} % Lingua portuguesa
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Codificação dos caracteres
\usepackage{indentfirst} % Indentar a primeira linha
\setlength{\parskip}{6pt} % Espaçamento entre parágrafos
\setlength{\parindent}{1.25cm} % Deslocamento da primeira linha
% \setlength{\baselineskip}{1em}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{hyperref} % Links
\usepackage[left=3cm,top=3cm,bottom=2cm,right=2cm]{geometry} % Margens
\usepackage{microtype} % Melhorias de justificação
\frenchspacing % Remover espaços extras
\usepackage{setspace} % Determinar espaçamento entrelinhas

% Títulos de seção em 12 pts %
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\fontsize{12}{12}\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\normalfont\fontsize{12}{12}\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\normalfont\fontsize{12}{12}\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{1.5em}{0.5em}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{1.5em}{0.5em}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{1.5em}{0.5em}

% Preâmbulo %
%\font\myfont=helvet at 12pt
\title{\normalsize{\textbf{Impossibilidade de expropriação de bitcoins: estruturas de incentivo para o cumprimento voluntário da execução}}} % Título do texto
\author{ \normalsize{\textbf{Pedro Corrêa dos Passos}}} % Autor
\date{} % Data

% Número da página alinhado à direita %

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyheadoffset{0cm}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} 
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhf{} \fancyhead[R]{\thepage}}


% Citações com singlespacing, 11 pts e margens %
\renewenvironment{quote}
  {\small\singlespacing\list{}{\rightmargin=0cm \leftmargin=4cm}%
   \item\relax}
  {\endlist}

%\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

% Texto %

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{gobble} % Remove a contagem de páginas
\singlespacing % Espaçamento simples


%\maketitle

\begin{center}
{\textbf{IMPOSSIBILIDADE DE EXPROPRIAÇÃO DE BITCOINS} \\ Estruturas de incentivo para o cumprimento voluntário da execução}\\
\end{center}
\begin{flushright}
{\textbf{Pedro Corrêa dos Passos}}\\
\end{flushright}

\noindent \textbf{RESUMO}\\
\noindent O problema de pesquisa surgiu com a inquietação acerca da impossibilidade de o Estado expropriar bitcoins (e outras criptomoedas) em casos de fraude a credores e fraude à execução, isto é, casos em que dolosamente o devedor se desfaz de seu patrimônio e o converte em criptomoedas com o dolo de não adimplir sua obrigação, seja decorrente da sentença ou de negócios jurídicos. A metodologia utilizada foi a análise do sistema de execução e cumprimento de sentença em vigor no ordenamento jurídico pátreo, bem como do protocolo Bitcoin. O resultado obtido das análises coaduna o entendimento do Tribunal de Justiça do Estado de São Paulo, \textit{ipsis litteris}, a penhora é possível, mas sua execução é improvável. Nesse sentido, tem-se sugestão \textit{lege ferenda} a fim de que haja mecanismos de dissuasão por parte do Estado, bem como utilizou-se da análise econômica do direito para que haja estruturas de incentivo que promovam o cumprimento voluntário da execução. \\
\noindent \textbf{Palavras-chave}: bitcoin. execução. análise econômica do direito. \\

\section*{INTRODUÇÃO}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\hphantom{\numberline{\thesection}}Introdução} % Insere a seção no sumário
\onehalfspacing % Espaçamento 1,5

Desde a criação da moeda, tem-se maior efetividade das atividades mercantis. Todavia, a sua criação sempre fora centralizada, quando oficiais, às mãos de governantes em sentido amplo, de modo a manter o poder sobre o mercado, por menor que seja, em estruturas que se assemelhavam à estrutura do Estado, até à própria estrutura estatal dos dias hodiernos.

Em verdade, a centralização desse poder expõe a dependência dos súditos e cidadãos às ações dos governantes e os efeitos nefastos que suas ações podem proporcionar à economia de um povo. São exemplos desse fenômeno a Grécia em 2013, os Estados Unidos na crise de 1929 com a liberação de crédito oriunda de ações governamentais e os Estados Unidos na crise de 2008, o Brasil na chamada “década perdida” e o Brasil a partir de 2013, entre tantos outros que se resumem basicamente à existência de um Banco Central que controle políticas monetárias.

Em 2008, um programador conhecido pelo pseudônimo Satoshi Nakamoto criou o protocolo do então chamado sistema Bitcoin, baseado em transações sem intermediários, em uma moeda não lastreada e em uma economia descentralizada, à parte de qualquer instituição central que gerencie a moeda.

O Bitcoin ganha destaque e expõe benefícios como menores custos de transação, maior acesso a serviços financeiros básicos e estimulo à inovação financeira, porquanto não dependa de intermediários, não seja controlado por nenhum poder capaz de impedir negociações ou manipular a moeda e o protocolo seja capaz de incentivar transações criptografadas, inclusive de ações de empresas ou outros ativos.

Os maiores desafios da criptomoeda se referem à volatilidade e ao uso para fins criminosos. Como qualquer outra moeda ou ativo, notícias e anúncios positivos acerca do Bitcoin fizeram com que novos investidores o buscassem, empurrando seu preço para cima e criando uma “bolha”. ULRICH (2014) traz que desde 2011 foram ao menos cinco ajustes de preço significativos. Quanto ao seu uso para fins criminosos, tem-se o exemplo do mercado negro Silk Road, que operava na deep web para transação de bens e serviços ilícitos, culminando na prisão de seu administrador Ross Ulbricht e um movimento promovido por senadores norte-americanos pela caçada ao Tor e ao Bitcoin.

\section{Execução e cumprimento de sentença}

\pagenumbering{arabic} % Contagem de páginas em algarismos arábicos
\setcounter{page}{2} % Estabelece o número da página

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec consectetur nisi ut sem porta, vitae tincidunt mi euismod. Morbi sit amet tristique nunc, sit amet eleifend massa. Sed blandit enim enim, quis ornare ante consequat sit amet. Sed in lacus leo. Nulla facilisi. Cras et faucibus mi. Donec posuere, turpis sed auctor accumsan, lorem nulla rutrum diam, non cursus elit purus quis nisi. Praesent mauris risus, sagittis at ipsum a, ullamcorper vulputate nulla. 

Phasellus elementum ante et porta porta. Pellentesque maximus ex et diam sollicitudin, et aliquam nisi lacinia. Phasellus non quam odio. Nam pellentesque felis posuere sapien blandit mattis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Praesent fringilla, tellus eget malesuada efficitur, nunc purus molestie tellus, at pretium enim quam sit amet orci. Proin urna lorem, gravida ut leo vel, molestie malesuada urna. Donec sagittis diam at erat consequat scelerisque. Suspendisse dictum lectus at diam condimentum, ac sodales massa consequat. Ut in mi lacinia, viverra quam quis, rhoncus neque. Morbi egestas felis non quam semper blandit. Sed eleifend arcu non turpis.

\subsection{Origens}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec consectetur nisi ut sem porta, vitae tincidunt mi euismod. Morbi sit amet tristique nunc, sit amet eleifend massa. Sed blandit enim enim, quis ornare ante consequat sit amet. Sed in lacus leo. Nulla facilisi. Cras et faucibus mi. Donec posuere, turpis sed auctor accumsan, lorem nulla rutrum diam, non cursus elit purus quis nisi. Praesent mauris risus, sagittis at ipsum a, ullamcorper vulputate nulla. 

Phasellus elementum ante et porta porta. Pellentesque maximus ex et diam sollicitudin, et aliquam nisi lacinia. Phasellus non quam odio. Nam pellentesque felis posuere sapien blandit mattis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Praesent fringilla, tellus eget malesuada efficitur, nunc purus molestie tellus, at pretium enim quam sit amet orci. Proin urna lorem, gravida ut leo vel, molestie malesuada urna. Donec sagittis diam at erat consequat scelerisque. Suspendisse dictum lectus at diam condimentum, ac sodales massa consequat. Ut in mi lacinia, viverra quam quis, rhoncus neque. Morbi egestas felis non quam semper blandit. Sed eleifend arcu non turpis.

\subsection{Meios de expropriação}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec consectetur nisi ut sem porta, vitae tincidunt mi euismod. Morbi sit amet tristique nunc, sit amet eleifend massa. Sed blandit enim enim, quis ornare ante consequat sit amet. Sed in lacus leo. Nulla facilisi. Cras et faucibus mi. Donec posuere, turpis sed auctor accumsan, lorem nulla rutrum diam, non cursus elit purus quis nisi. Praesent mauris risus, sagittis at ipsum a, ullamcorper vulputate nulla. 

Phasellus elementum ante et porta porta. Pellentesque maximus ex et diam sollicitudin, et aliquam nisi lacinia. Phasellus non quam odio. Nam pellentesque felis posuere sapien blandit mattis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Praesent fringilla, tellus eget malesuada efficitur, nunc purus molestie tellus, at pretium enim quam sit amet orci. Proin urna lorem, gravida ut leo vel, molestie malesuada urna. Donec sagittis diam at erat consequat scelerisque. Suspendisse dictum lectus at diam condimentum, ac sodales massa consequat. Ut in mi lacinia, viverra quam quis, rhoncus neque. Morbi egestas felis non quam semper blandit. Sed eleifend arcu non turpis.

\subsubsection{Penhor e leilão}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec consectetur nisi ut sem porta, vitae tincidunt mi euismod. Morbi sit amet tristique nunc, sit amet eleifend massa. Sed blandit enim enim, quis ornare ante consequat sit amet. Sed in lacus leo. Nulla facilisi. Cras et faucibus mi. Donec posuere, turpis sed auctor accumsan, lorem nulla rutrum diam, non cursus elit purus quis nisi. Praesent mauris risus, sagittis at ipsum a, ullamcorper vulputate nulla. 

Phasellus elementum ante et porta porta. Pellentesque maximus ex et diam sollicitudin, et aliquam nisi lacinia. Phasellus non quam odio. Nam pellentesque felis posuere sapien blandit mattis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Praesent fringilla, tellus eget malesuada efficitur, nunc purus molestie tellus, at pretium enim quam sit amet orci. Proin urna lorem, gravida ut leo vel, molestie malesuada urna. Donec sagittis diam at erat consequat scelerisque. Suspendisse dictum lectus at diam condimentum, ac sodales massa consequat. Ut in mi lacinia, viverra quam quis, rhoncus neque. Morbi egestas felis non quam semper blandit. Sed eleifend arcu non turpis.

\subsubsection{Adjudicação}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec consectetur nisi ut sem porta, vitae tincidunt mi euismod. Morbi sit amet tristique nunc, sit amet eleifend massa. Sed blandit enim enim, quis ornare ante consequat sit amet. Sed in lacus leo. Nulla facilisi. Cras et faucibus mi. Donec posuere, turpis sed auctor accumsan, lorem nulla rutrum diam, non cursus elit purus quis nisi. Praesent mauris risus, sagittis at ipsum a, ullamcorper vulputate nulla. 

Phasellus elementum ante et porta porta. Pellentesque maximus ex et diam sollicitudin, et aliquam nisi lacinia. Phasellus non quam odio. Nam pellentesque felis posuere sapien blandit mattis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Praesent fringilla, tellus eget malesuada efficitur, nunc purus molestie tellus, at pretium enim quam sit amet orci. Proin urna lorem, gravida ut leo vel, molestie malesuada urna. Donec sagittis diam at erat consequat scelerisque. Suspendisse dictum lectus at diam condimentum, ac sodales massa consequat. Ut in mi lacinia, viverra quam quis, rhoncus neque. Morbi egestas felis non quam semper blandit. Sed eleifend arcu non turpis.

\section{Bitcoin}

Antes de, propriamente, dissertar sobre o sistema Bitcoin, faz-se necessário tratar da ideia própria de moeda e seus desdobramentos no desenvolvimento da criptomoeda. É importante esclarecer que o viés econômico é mister no sentido de embasar a teoria sobre a qual o Direito se debruçará no invariável momento de sua regulação.

\subsection{O que é moeda}

Para conceituar moeda, deve-se ter em vista que o uso cotidiano do termo deve ser posto de lado. FREDERIC MISHKIN (2000) nos traz:

\begin{quote}
A palavra moeda, conforme é usada em conversações diárias, pode significar muitas coisas, mas para os economistas ela tem um significado muito específico. \\ (...) \\ Os economistas definem moeda (também chamada de oferta de moeda) como qualquer coisa que seja geralmente aceita em pagamento por bens ou serviços ou no pagamento final de dívidas. \\ (...) \\ Definir moeda meramente como dinheiro é muito limitado para os economistas. Uma vez que cheques também são aceitos como pagamentos para compras, depósitos em contas correntes são considerados moedas também. Frequentemente uma definição ainda mais ampla de moeda é necessária porque outros itens, como depósitos de poupança, podem funcionar como moeda se puderem ser rápida e facilmente convertidos em dinheiro ou depósitos de conta corrente. (...)
\end{quote}

É de se notar, portanto, que a conceituação da moeda não se dá de modo uníssono e MISHKIN (2000) trata, portanto, da moeda sob a perspectiva de suas funções primordiais: como meio de pagamento, como unidade de conta e como reserva de valor, sendo que a “função como meio de pagamento é o que distingue a moeda de outros ativos como ações, bônus e casas”.

O aperfeiçoamento da res enquanto moeda se dá, a priori, pela capacidade de utilizá-la como forma de pagamento por bens e serviços. Um primeiro questionamento que se poderia fazer seria no sentido de buscar entender a necessidade de se ter algo como moeda, se os próprios bens ou serviços são intercambiáveis per se. 

Ocorre que, para fazê-lo, indivíduos deveriam se encontrar com interesses recíprocos em seus bens ou serviços a oferecer. A moeda surge para servir como intermediária nas trocas, em civilizações pautadas pelo escambo. A partir do momento em que há uma referência para as negociações, não há mais a necessidade das buscas por interesses recíprocos. Trata-se de segurança, quanto à referência de valor, e de uma análise de custo benefício.

\subsubsection{Moeda como meio de pagamento e reserva de valor}

A res, para se configurar como moeda, em atenção à função de servir como meio de pagamento, deve observar alguns pontos, dentre os quais MISHKIN (2000) traz: deve ser de fácil padronização, grande aceitabilidade e divisibilidade, deve ser fácil de carregar e não deve se deteriorar rapidamente.

O primeiro ponto diz respeito à simplificação no processo de determinar o valor da moeda. Dessa forma, seguindo um padrão de clareza, a moeda facilmente é criada quando a personalização da res torna fácil a identificação do valor que tem em si mesma.

Quanto à aceitabilidade e divisibilidade, tem-se que a moeda deve ser aceita pelas pessoas, de modo que a facilidade em realizar as transações comerciais se concretiza na medida em que é aceita pelo mercado. A divisibilidade, noutro giro, se refere ao troco, isto é, garantir que transações de pequeno valor comercial ocorram, também.

A facilidade de carregar se resume à praticidade que faz parte da ideia própria de moeda. Ela surge como meio para facilitar transações, não para dificultá-las. Nesse sentido, a moeda não pode ser de difícil manuseio, de modo a criar novos óbices às negociações.

A necessidade de não se deteriorar rapidamente resume a ideia de reserva de valor. A ideia é que mantenha o poder de compra no curso do tempo. Sendo o ativo com maior liquidez, por ser o próprio meio de pagamento, deve preservar, em si, seu valor.

Por estes critérios, qualquer coisa se poderia transformar em moeda, e de fato a assertiva está correta. MISHKIN (2000) nos elucida:

\begin{quote}
As formas de moeda que satisfizeram estes critérios tomaram muitas formas incomuns através da história humana, estendendo-se desde wampum (cordões de contas) usados pelos nativos americanos até tabaco e uísque, usados pelos primeiros colonizadores americanos, a cigarros, usados em campos de prisioneiros durante a Segunda Guerra Mundial. A diversidade de formas de moeda que têm se desenvolvido através dos anos é tanto um testemunho da inventividade da raça humano quanto do desenvolvimento de ferramentas e linguagem.
\end{quote}

Destarte, a moeda é criada com o objetivo de facilitar negociações, aperfeiçoar os processos mercantis e dar maior efetividade ao mercado, instituto existente desde os primórdios das civilizações.

\subsection{O que é bitcoin}

Bitcoin, conforme leciona ULRICH (2014), é um sistema de código aberto que se pauta por transações de ponto a ponto (ou peer-to-peer, em inglês) em que a unidade monetária a que se referem tais transações recebe o nome do próprio sistema: bitcoin.

Algumas características devem ser ressalvadas, como o fato de ser um sistema descentralizado (por isso ser ponto a ponto), estritamente digital e principiologicamente sem intermediários.

A descentralização diz respeito a não existir um controlador central do sistema, mas o sistema é quem se autorregula, pelos seus usuários. De fato, por manter um livro-razão público em que são conferidas as transações de bitcoins, a verificação de autenticidade da moeda se dá pelos próprios usuários.

A moeda é estritamente digital porque é, basicamente, um protocolo, um conjunto de regras que determinam a existência de cada moeda digital e por não possuir correspondente físico, em papel-moeda, o que será abordado em tópico oportuno.

Quanto a ser principiologicamente livre de intermediários, tem-se a ideia que deu origem ao sistema: ser capaz de realizar transações de modo seguro sem que seja necessário um terceiro de confiança, como o PayPal ou o PagSeguro, para garantir que o dinheiro não seja gasto duas vezes, o problema do “gasto duplo”.

\subsection{Como funciona o bitcoin}

O Bitcoin, porquanto seja um sistema essencialmente de pagamentos, não de registros, funciona com base em criptografia de chave pública. É dizer que, quando criptografada, o proprietário da moeda recebe duas chaves, uma pública e uma privada. No momento da transação, a chave pública é anotada no blockchain, com a anotação de que fora assinada pela chave privada pelo anterior proprietário.

\section{Estruturas de incentivo para o cumprimento voluntário da execução}

\section*{Conclusão}

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\hphantom{\numberline{\thesection}}Conclusão}

Conclusão.

\newpage

\section*{Bibliografia}

\pagenumbering{gobble} % Remove a contagem de páginas
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\hphantom{\numberline{\thesection}}Bibliografia}

\noindent MISHKIN, F. S. \textbf{Moedas, Bancos e Mercados Financeiros}. Tradução de Christiane Pinto Ferreira Studart. 5. ed. Rio de Janeiro: LTC, 2000.

\noindent ULRICH, F. \textbf{Bitcoin - A Moeda na Era Digital}. 1. ed. São Paulo: Instituto Ludwig Von Mises Brasil, 2014.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Off-topic: you are loading `hyperref` too early. You need `\selectfont` after using a low-level font-switch such as `\fontsize`. You are misusing `\\ `. Surely this gives many bad boxes? Are you really typesetting your bibliography like that? Not even using `thebibliography`?

Comment: The hidelinks option at `\documentclass` hides all of those boxes. I don't use the `\thebibliography` 'cause I only make references by using (SURNAME, Year), not ever footnotes, so it doesn't makes any difference to me.

What is the point about loading `hyperref` after `\selectfont`? And where am I missing the double backslashes?

Comment: You aren't missing `\\ `. You're misusing them. `hyperref` should be loaded late - last with certain exceptions (notably `cleveref`. I don't get the point about footnotes. I use author-year, but I still use keys for referencing, as anything else would be a nightmare. (I use Biblatex/Biber, but that's not the point here.)

Comment: Seeing your preamble, I cannot help but think that using LaTeX to achieve a Word-like result is pointless.